# How to install or configure Angular 2 app on AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, angular, command-line-interface

I have installed angular-cli and node in AWS EC2 server. After that i cloned my angular 2 app from Git repository i.e BitBucket to server. The problem is when i enter the ip address of my server in browser the app is not running. As angular 2 uses localhost:4200 if you are running locally but how to tell to server that which url need to use.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, there are literally *n* number of ways to do this. You have to do exactly what you would do on your Mac's terminal. You just have an additional step of `SSH`ing to your EC2 instance.

1. Open Mac Terminal.
2. SSH to your EC2 terminal.
3. Install node, npm there.
4. Clone angular 2's [seed repository](https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed).
5. run `npm install` to install dependencies
6. run `npm start` to fire up dev server